# want to retrieve the value of these slots from firebase,store it in a String n check,if the value is'booked',then disable the button showing a message

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase Database sample screenshot:

[image]

I want to retrieve the value of all these slots(slot1,..,slot4) from firebase and store it in a String and check, if the value is 'booked', then disable the button showing a toast message! I don't know what mistake I'm doing, can someone please help me fix it

```
mdatabaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("CheckAvailability");
    mdatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            checkStatus(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    })
```

}

```
private void checkStatus(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    String s1,s2,s3,s4;

    for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        Fdata fdata=new Fdata();
        fdata.setSlot1(ds.child("CheckAvailability").getValue(Fdata.class).getSlot1());
        fdata.setSlot2(ds.child("CheckAvailability").getValue(Fdata.class).getSlot2());
        fdata.setSlot3(ds.child("CheckAvailability").getValue(Fdata.class).getSlot3());
        fdata.setSlot4(ds.child("CheckAvailability").getValue(Fdata.class).getSlot4());

        s1=fdata.getSlot1();
        s2=fdata.getSlot2();
        s3=fdata.getSlot3();
        s4=fdata.getSlot4();

        if(s1.equals("booked")){
            mButtonS1.setEnabled(false);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Slot 1 Already booked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if(s2.equals("booked")){
            mButtonS1.setEnabled(false);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Slot 2 Already booked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if(s3.equals("booked")){
            mButtonS1.setEnabled(false);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Slot 3 Already booked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if(s4.equals("booked")){
            mButtonS1.setEnabled(false);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Slot 4 Already booked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. Also, please don't abuse bold formatting

Comment: So, you really  didn't ask a question, and i don't know what problem do you have. But i believe you can solve it by merging four "if" in to one "if"

Comment: finding difficulty in fetching the values of slot...I want to retrieve the values of slot1,....,slot4 and disable the button if the value is "booked"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I knew where is your code problem
in this line `fdata.setSlot1(ds.child("CheckAvailability").getValue(Fdata.class).getSlot1());`
there are two mistakes:

- you refer to "CheckAvailability" child while you should refer to child inside it like "Slot1", because you refer to "CheckAvailability" earlier in `mdatabaseReference`.
- you use **getValue()** method with wrong type data(Fdata.class), should be use(String.class) instead of that.

The solution is:

```
mdatabaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("CheckAvailability");
mdatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String s1,s2,s3,s4;

            s1 = dataSnapshot.child("Slot1").getValue(String.class);
            s2 = dataSnapshot.child("Slot2").getValue(String.class);
            s3 = dataSnapshot.child("Slot3").getValue(String.class);
            s4 = dataSnapshot.child("Slot4").getValue(String.class);

            if(s1.equals("booked")){
                mButtonS1.setEnabled(false);
                Toast.makeText(this,"Slot 1 Already booked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if(s2.equals("booked")){
                mButtonS1.setEnabled(false);
                Toast.makeText(this,"Slot 2 Already booked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if(s3.equals("booked")){
                mButtonS1.setEnabled(false);
                Toast.makeText(this,"Slot 3 Already booked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if(s4.equals("booked")){
                mButtonS1.setEnabled(false);
                Toast.makeText(this,"Slot 4 Already booked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
})
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Hey, this didn't work for me...still getting null values

Comment: please try again now, and tell me what happens

Comment: there was wrong with close brackets before the update it.                                 

before:
`fdata.setSlot1(da.child("Slot1")).getValue(String.clsss);`


                              after:
`fdata.setSlot1(da.child("Slot1").getValue(String.clsss));`

Comment: yeah, I understood that and made the changes in the syntax.

Comment: is there any alternative way to get the value of these slots, maybe with a different logic???

Comment: nope! still getting null values!! dude can you please share your email Id, so that I can share my work with you and get a solution over this

Comment: don't worry, This is the best place for this discussion.
please screenshot for the whole your database.

Comment: {
  "CheckAvailability" : {
    "Slot1" : "booked",
    "Slot2" : "booked",
    "Slot3" : "empty",
    "Slot4" : "empty"
  },
  "userDetails" : {
    "AP38102019" : {
      "arrTime" : "0:18",
      "date" : "2019-02-26",
      "slot" : "Slot4",
      "uid" : "AP38102019",
      "uname" : "mansuk bhai",
      "vno" : "MH 09 FF 5555"
    },
    "AP58932019" : {
      "arrTime" : "0:30",
      "date" : "2019-02-25",
      "slot" : "Slot1",
      "uid" : "AP58932019",
      "uname" : "rohan",
      "vno" : "MH 01 AB 1234"
    }
  }
}

Comment: this is the whole database in json, please help me retrieve the slot information. I tried all the above suggested method, but all i got was a null value everytime

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, now you can get "slots" from datasnapshot directly, tell me what happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s1=dataSnapshot.child("CheckAvailability").child("Slot1").getValue(String.class);
```

I tried out doing this and it worked for me!!